# trace the code line which made ajax Request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chrome-app-developer-tool

I have a big project which i am new too instead of writing alert i would like to know where the call is being made from.
Is there any way to trace the code line which made ajax Request in Javascript.

Comment: Use your console? All modern browsers support xmlhttp logging. Try console.log('message'); for debugging purposes.

Comment: if(window.console) {
    console.log(debug information);
} if the console is not available the script will crash. so window.console checks if the console object is there and if so it uses its log function to print out debug information.

Comment: Chrome dev tools \ Network \ Filter XHR \ Initiator column. Hover to see call stack.

Comment: Yury Tarabanko thanks for your reply. I can only see the url while hovering.

Comment: Thanks sanjay and Kevin Op den Kamp

Comment: Thanks Yury Can you post that as an answer so that i can mark it?